# binding attributes - can I have a primitive boolean?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Is it possible to bind an attribute to a variable which returns a primitive boolean and have that boolean stored?

If this wasn't clear, the following example should explain it:

data context (model / controller)

```
present: true
```

handlebars template

```
<div {{bindAttr data-present="present"}}>foo</div>

console.log($(div).attr('data-present')) // I'd like it to return true
```

Comment: can you setup a jsbin that show's what you are trying to do?

Comment: @intuitivepixel oh, sorry, I made a mistake - console.log *should* return true but it doesn't. Basically as I didn't know how to do it the Ember way, I tried to pass a boolean value to bootstrap modal which was rendered as a view.

Comment: I think I should have used Ember/Bootstrap package.

Answer (score 1):

Ember uses the same convention as HTML for boolean attributes. When binding against boolean values, the attribute value would take the name of the attribute. Eg:- `{{disabled='someVar'}}` would be rendered as `disabled=disabled` if `someVar` is true and the attribute would be removed if `someVar` is false.

So in this case you can expect the `data-present` value to also be `data-present` when `present` variable is true.

I tried this in a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/uweziz/1/). The elements inspector confirms this.